# SSL in a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, ssl

Suppose I'm creating a Wordpress website with user login and a small e-commerce.

When user logins in, she uses `http://www.mysite.com/login/`. When se buys something, she uses `http://www.mysite.com/mycart/` where credit card info is entered.

How do I use SSL in this setup? I mean, I should redirect `http://www.mysite.com/login/` to `https://www.mysite.com/login/`, and return to http, then when in `http://www.mysite.com/mycart/` to `https://www.mysite.com/mycart/`? How do I do all these redirects?

(I'm planning to use a SSL from a shared hosting environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) - and then integrate your shopping cart.

Comment: Aside from using that SSL and setting it up in your wp-config file you should also use a 301 redirect from the http to the https version of that /login/ page, so it initiates the SSL.